# Child is detected with parents tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tags, parent-child

I wanted to make a simple prototype of a 2D character swinging a sword, so I attached the player tag to the parent and attached the sword as a child with a Weapon tag. I want the player to die when being touched by an enemy but the enemy to die when its being touched by the sword.

I have attached the respawning script to the player which detects when the enemy touches it, however it seems to also be triggered when the enemy is touching the sword child. I have tried to tell it to only trigger when interacting with this.tag Player but it didn't help.

Do I have to separate the sword completely or is something that could help me out here?

Here is the code I tried

```
if (other.tag == "Enemy" && this.tag == "Player")
{ 
   foreach (GameObject enemy in enemies)
   {
      enemy.GetComponent<EnemyAI>().EnemyRespawn();
   }
   Respawn();
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you made sure, that the weapon is outside of the player collider, or in other words: Is your player collider overlapping with the weapon, if so, then the [OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) Method would be triggered at the right time, because visually the weapon and not the player would be touched, but the players collider as well.

I hope, that you understand, what I mean by that, if not, comment on this answer.

Greetings, Mario

Comment: Ah, thank you that makes sense! It really was overlapping so that would be the correct answer! I have by now gone with a different solution by making both the character as well as the weapon children of the main player object and so seperating the two but this is very good to know going forward or if this solution doesnt work out! Thanks for taking the time!!